# Make responsive images fill div with a percent height

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm trying to make an "intro"-section for my website which should take up to around 80% of the current (when page is loaded) viewport height and contain two images: one to the left and one to the right of the section. Beneath these two images, a down arrow should be displayed, teasing the client to scroll down for the next section.

Thing is, if I set my intro div to `height: 80%` and set the images `width:100%` to make them responsive, they overflow the intro div which is set to 80% height.

I made a sample [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwBXOL?editors=1100#0) to illustrate my problem.

I set the opacity to 0.5 so you can see where my intro div is.

Is there any way to make the images fit their divs in a way where I don't have to put `overflow:hidden;` on my intro div?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mmmm at some point the img will need to overflow the container or width or height if you want to cover the full div without distort the img

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this scenario, you'll probably want to use background images on divs instead of normal img tags:

```
<div style="background-image:url(myimage.jpg)"></div>
```

On these divs, set the following css:

```
background-size:cover;
```

If you have a demo started on jsfiddle.net or similar, I can help with more specifics.

Comment: thanks! :-) I created this jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/yw7yqvd3/ Setting it to background-size:cover makes it not fill the width of the container though, but the height is correct. I guess I'm asking too much from the browser here ;-)

Comment: @BoMortensen I don't understand you want always 100% of width and 100% of height ?

Comment: DaniP: I guess I just want to make the image as "centered" as possible in the div. Not sure it's possible though. I'll stick with @kthornbloom's solution to use background-size:cover. Using background-image, I don't have to use  `position:absolute;` on other elements such as text, button etc in the div :-)

Comment: @BoMortensen It should totally fill the div. Here's an update of your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yw7yqvd3/4/

Answer (score 0):

You could use viewport height unit as such: `height: 80vh;` but using it with `width: 100%;` might break your images aspect ratio; as kthornbloom said just before, you can use background images to fill the entire parent element.

Answer (score 0):

background-image is the way to go. Note that you will have to add height: 100%;
to #intro div so as to inherit the parent element's height